# Pentaho Javascript - row manipulation

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to manipulate a row using javascript in an older version of pentaho 4.4) and getting some strange results that I can't explain / don't understand what Pentaho is doing

```
var test = 'field';
Alert (this[test]); //--> Undefined
Alert (this['field']); // --> Expected result
Alert (this[test]); //--> Expected Result
```

For some reason, the initial request for `this[test]` is undefined until I use the literal string reference making it impossible to dynamically drive the process (i.e. I can't access row information by references).

Any ideas as to why? Is it simply how Pentaho deals with variables? Effectively I want my end result to allow me to change the row value at any given position. Either:

```
row[test] = 'New value
```

or

```
this[test] = 'New Value
```

or

```
this[test].setValue('New Value');
```

However, none of the above work, without replacing the values making it a very static process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, Kettle does not add a field to the script's scope, unless the field is contained as a substring in the script source code (it should add even if the field mentioned in the comment). See `determineUsedFields()` and `addValues()` methods (https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/4.4.0/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/steps/scriptvalues_mod/ScriptValuesMod.java#L106).

So, the exact script you've provided, actually, produces either three defined values, or three undefined values, depending on whether the field exists or not. I was able to reproduce your issue only after I've removed strings with the field name from the code completely, and passed the field name in another field.

So, one way to manipulate row values could be to mention all field names in the script (e.g. in a comment), then try to use setValue as you have tried (seems to work in compatibility mode only).

Another possible way is to use the `row` array variable to get values and `getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(fieldName)` to get the index of the field, e.g:

```
var idx = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(fieldName)
// WARNING: you may assign value of any type this way
// and the value will not be converted to a type defined
// in the field's ValueMeta:
row[idx] = 'New value'
```

However, this approach bypasses type conversions, which are usually performed while passing JavaScript values outside of the JS step in `getValueFromJScript()` method.

For example, the following code will put invalid value in the output, and you may not even notice it until some subsequent step will handle the value in some improper way:

```
// Let's assume that fieldName is name of the 0th input field.
// I'd expect, that the value would remain the same
// but in fact the `fieldName` references some wrapper oject
// which looks similar to its value
// but has a different type
row[0] = fieldName;
```

In subsequent JS step:

```
for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    Alert(row[i]) // alerts same value as the input, e.g. 'test'
    Alert(row[i].class) // alerts undefined. While expected is 'java.lang.String'
    // Some other subsequent steps may crash once this value encountered
}
```